# A simple curl command causes this ridiculousness

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

In my Spring Boot 1.5.12 application with Spring Data REST and Spring Security, a trivial delete mapping is misbehaving when I issue a `DELETE` via `curl`:

```
    curl -u 'admin:password' -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/shoes/20
```

The server fails with a Spring Data REST exception:

```
    ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not found!
```

when it tries to resolve the ridiculous URL:

```
    /api/shoes/api/shoes/20
```

which looks like it's a combination of `/api/shoes` (the resource) and `/api/shoes/20` (the item being deleted). This URL does not exist, of course...but where is this URL coming from? The endpoint is trivial (with Lombok):

```
@RepositoryRestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ShoeRepositoryRestController {
  @DeleteMapping("/shoes/{id}")
  public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long shoeId) {
    log.error("handle delete");
  }
}
```

which prints the error message in the log, followed by the `ResourceNotFoundException`. The repository is similarly generic:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "shoes", path = "shoes")
public interface ShoeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Shoe, Long> {
  // a set of query methods...
}
```

And the `WebSecurity` configuration authorizes the delete (obviously):

```
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/shoes/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
```

Perhaps Spring Security is trying to do something with the submitted URL (`/api/shoes/20`) after apparently successful handling, and that something is mishandled somehow. There is no redirection after the delete handler.

Any ideas what might be awry?

Comment: Can you show us the entire class ? It's may be a problem with the rest controller declaration

Comment: do you have any `redirection` in your app ?

Comment: It also could be a conflict with rest repository from spring data. Could you show us repository interface ?

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure the request is not processed twice ? The first time, the resource is deleted and the second time it doesn't exist so spring data throw an exception

Comment: Rest repository automatically add rest controller and handle the request

Comment: Yes, @MartinChoraine, I'm aware that SDR adds rest controllers but I need to intercept these with a service layer API.

Comment: It's possible it's being processed twice but I don't know from where...

Comment: I think you shouldn't do it with a rest controller but should look at RepositoryEventHandler to intercept request

Comment: I couldn't understand at your post: Is the `/api/shoes/api/shoes/20` working?

Comment: @MartinChoraine -- I think this is a bit off-topic but I use controllers, service methods, and repository event handlers throughout the application but the `RepositoryEventHandler` sit just above the repository, below the controller and service APIs.

Comment: @Dherik -- the `/api/shoes/api/shoes/20` is a non-sense URL, likely combined from `/api/shoes/` (root of the resource) and `/api/shoes/20` which is the item being deleted. This non-sense URL triggers the resource not found...

Comment: @JanNielsen, it's a non-sense a URL, but I couldn't understand why you mentioned this specific URL in your question.

Comment: The non-sense URL is what the server is processing when it fails -- and it's unclear where this non-sense URL is coming from...which is the root of my question. The controller seems to handle the delete as it should and then, somehow, it starts working on this silly URL when it should just be returning to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! Add a response entity return:

```
  @DeleteMapping("/shoes/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long shoeId) {
    log.error("handle delete");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
```

There should be better handling of this programming error...